# What are the rules for talking when you are not in the pot?

Tags: rules

Watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z44hQPWt6QY) video at one point the commentator gets almost irritated at players who are not in the pot talking with one another, is this common? Will players talk when not in the pot or is this considered bad etiquette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it wrong.  Commentator was not irritated with people not in hand talking.  There was very little table chit chat.

A player IN the hand was talking about the hand. In the hand or not you cannot talk about the hand while the hand is in play. A player in the hand can ask stuff like how much you got behind. You are not supposed to speculate on what a player is holding nor indicate the strength of your hand. You cannot suggest action.

An all in player commented about the hand. I think he was even suggesting what action to take. In that spot he should not be talking at all.

Some times last to act two way can talk about about their hand.  This was a 3 way pot.  And the person talking was not last to act.

Answer (score 1):

Its very common and basically allowed. Poker after all is a social game. However there can be exceptions loud disruptive talking is not allowed, and talking about the hand in progress is not allowed. Casinos are loud places, one needs to deal with it.

Comment: Why did it then seem to be a problem for the commentator?

Comment: @NeilMeyer Paparazzo provides a fair explanation.